# Is it productive to use a Stylus with the iPad?

Tags: ipad, stylus, drawing

My son loves drawing comics.  He wants to do it now on my iPad 3.  Does anyone have experience with using a Stylus for such an activity?

Does it make sense or will it be an exercise in futility?  I've looked at the Wacom Bamboo and Cosmonaut stylus.  Are either of these (or some other ones) suitable for drawing comics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only downside to drawing on the iPad with a stylus is that you have to keep your hand and wrist off the screen, which can become uncomfortable for those artists that still draw with their wrist (which is something one ought to change anyway).  Some apps claim to have wrist protection, but none of them are very good.

However, I know many artists do use the iPad and other tablets for creating art.  They have changed their drawing habits and draw with their whole arm, and use the zoom feature to create detail they would normally create with their wrist touching the drawing surface.

I am not an artist, but I do enjoy drawing, and I found that a pen size stylus gives me the precision I prefer, and doesn't obscure much of the screen.  I suspect the Cosmonaut would obscure more of the screen, being a thicker tool.  This is something that is up to the user's preference, though - he might prefer a larger grip, or weight.

Be prepared to test out a dozen or more drawing apps.  I found procreate meets my needs, but I also have several others, and each has merits to recommend it.

Comment: Can you recommend a specific app (specifically that supports zooming to create detail)?  Also, does it work to wear a garden glove with fingers cut off to not have to deal with the wrist business at all?

Comment: @AngryHacker [Procreate](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/procreate-sketch-paint-create./id425073498?mt=8) allows you to zoom and rotate your image as you draw so you don't need to move the iPad around.  It is a very highly rated and popular drawing package for artists. I believe garden gloves or fingerless cycling gloves would work.  Try it out and if not, add some padding on the side that touches the iPad or use thicker gloves.

Answer (score 1):

The Cosmonaut is about the only stylus worth the effort in my opinion. I've tried a few different ones, but the Cosmo' has always felt right. I think it's to do with it's weighting and general sturdy feel.

I think with practice your son will produce excellent results using the Cosmonaut, especially with the right app (Paper or Sketchbook Pro are excellent for art.)

--

'Random' 2yr update: After using the Cosmonaut on and off for the last couple of years, mainly with Paper by 53 and Procreate, I feel a small update is in order.

I've used the stylus with the iPad 3, iPad 4, iPad mini and iPad Air. I've noticed a gradual loss of effectiveness of the stylus - it feels harder to use resistance-wise than it used to. Could be a change in screen surface technology or just the wear-and-tear you'd expect from using a stylus. So my opinion of this has lessened to a degree. Perhaps Paper's 'Pencil' product will be the one for me, when it's finally available for non-silly money in the UK.